# Crear un enlace tipo asset en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Se qué utilizar asset hace una referencia a nuestra `app/public` pero hay alguna manera de crear otro enlace es decir, para tener una mejor estructura y tener referencia de las rutas.

Ejemplo:

```
public
---assets
---images
---thumbnails
```

en mi blade tengo que colocar:

`{{asset('/images/image-1.jpg')}}`

pero como puedo crear un enlace directo a `images`? de tal manera que el código quede de la siguiente manera:

```
{{images('image-1.jpg')}}
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes crear un helper personalizado. Para comrnzar debes crear un archivo en la carpeta del proyecto, puedes utilizar `config` o `app`

```
// app/helpers.php

<?php
function images($path = '')
{
    return asset("/images/$path");
}
```

Ahora debes modificar el archivo `composer.json` para agregar una key `files`

```
"files": [
    "app/helpers.php"
]
```

Luego debes ejecutar

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Tu helper estara agregado y puedes usarlo en cualquier parte como

```
images('image-1.jpg');
```