# Algo va mal en este helper de Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una página de noticias  donde saco toda la información de la Base de datos. Imprimo el titulo con un `{{ $item->titulo }}` sin ningún problema. El problema me viene al poner la descripción, al utilizar como `textarea` el TinyMCE en la base de datos lo guarda del siguiente modo `<p>La idea de <strong>High As</strong> naci&oacute; donde ....` entonces para mostrarlo en la página hago así:

```
@php echo  Str::limit($item->cuerpo, 150) @endphp
```

De este modo no saca los `<p>` y formatea bien el texto. Pero el problema me viene que en esos 150 caracteres si pilla un `<b>` en medio, me destroza las siguientes iteraciones de las noticias y me lo pone todo en `<b>`.

Alguna sugerencia??

Comment: Crea un helper propio, no tienes más que contar los `<` que existen antes de por donde quieres *cortar*, y si los hay pues decides cortar antes de él, o buscar el cierre de ese tag y cortar a continuación

Comment: O quita las etiquetas y luego limita el string. Ago así `Str::limit(strip_tags($item->cuerpo), 150)`

Comment: Pero @Benito-B no todos llevan el `<b>` en el mismo sitio, pero no se si te he entendido bien, gracias

Comment: No entiendo @porloscerrosΨ de que me sirve eso, puedes poner un ejemplo??

Comment: [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) > Retira las etiquetas HTML y PHP de un string. El ejemplo es ese que puse en el comentario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo instalada la extensión libxml de PHP, lo más fácil sería usar el método `loadHTML()` del objeto `DOMDocument`. Este auto analiza HTML mal formado y una llamada posterior a `saveHTML()` generará el HTML válido.

```
@php 
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(utf8_decode(Str::limit($item->cuerpo, 150)));
    $string = $doc->saveHTML();

    echo $string;
@endphp

{!!$string!!}
```

Te dejo un snnipet de laravel playground:

https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/dfb13f3a-5378-4bc6-82e8-bccd266e3b7e

Ref: [Modelo de Objetos de Documento](https://www.php.net/dom)

---

Si no puedes instalar la extensión `libxml` por alguna razón, puedes apelar a los regex. Por ejemplo:

```
@php
function closetags($html) {
    preg_match_all('#<([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
    $openedtags = $result[1];
    preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);

    $closedtags = $result[1];
    $len_opened = count($openedtags);

    if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {
        return $html;
    }
    $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {
        if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)) {
            $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
        } else {
            unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

echo closetags(Str::limit($item->cuerpo, 150));
@endphp

{!!$string!!}
```

Snnipet de laravel playground:

https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/3aee73af-1ad7-4651-a121-7c7ece77c5dd

---

Finalmente, para no tener todo ese código feo en tu vista, puedes [crearte un helper personalizado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/323300/92278)

Para comenzar debes crear un archivo en un directorio del proyecto, puedes utilizar por ejemplo `app`:

```
// app/helpers.php

<?php
function close_tags($html)
{
    preg_match_all('#<([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
    $openedtags = $result[1];
    preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);

    $closedtags = $result[1];
    $len_opened = count($openedtags);

    if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {
        return $html;
    }
    $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {
        if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)) {
            $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
        } else {
            unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Luego debes modificar el archivo `composer.json` para agregar una key `files` bajo la llave `:autoload`:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
    //... 
 },
```

Finalmente debes ejecutar:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Tu helper estará agregado y puedes usarlo en cualquier parte como

```
{!!close_tags(Str::limit($item->cuerpo, 150))!!}
```

Comment: Hola @porloscerros Ψ perdona que es estado cinco dias sin conexión, voy a probarlo y te digo

Comment: Hola de nuevo @porloscerros Ψ el `key files` hay que ponerlo en algun sitio necesariamente en el archivo `composer.json` ? es que no me lo reconoce

Comment: Hola, sí, va dentro de `autoload`.

Comment: Perfecto funciona a la perfección, y has puesto una respuesta de 10. Muchas gracias.