# Usar una función externa en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

La situación es la siguiente:
Tengo un archivo llamado helpers que tienen funciones comunes y quisiera usarlo dentro de controladores y modelos en la aplicación en la que trabajo.
La estructura de la carpeta es la siguiente:

myApp
|_____app
...........|___models
...........|.....| _ User
...........|__*helpers

................|* helpers
el archivo helpers tiene su propio namespace `namespace App\Helpers`
Bien, a la hora de usar una función dentro del archivo User hago lo siguiente:
`use function App\Helpers\{getFormatedDate};`
y cuando intento llamar la función lo hago de la siguiente manera: `$date=getFormatedDate();`
pero obtengo el siguiente error `Call to undefined function App\Helpers\getFormatedDate()`
No tengo claro dónde está el error; si en la forma de usar los espacios de nombre o si tengo que usar el require_once para añardir el contenido del archivo

Comment: `getFormatedDate` es una función o es una clase que tiene su propio método invoke?

Comment: Es solamente una función

Comment: Agregaste el archivo al autoload de composer?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ No, no agregué el archivo

Comment: Tendrías que hacer algo para que php cargue esas funciones, por ejemplo via composer. Recuerdo que ya se hizo esta pregunta en SO, pero no la encuentro ahora. Fijate en este tutorial, que está explicado https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

Comment: Ahí encontré una respuesta en el sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323290/crear-un-enlace-tipo-asset-en-laravel/323300#323300

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias:)

Comment: Vale. Lo que te pediría es que si lo resolviste con lo que dice en esa respuesta, marquemos esta pregunta como duplicado de aquella. O si querés agregar una respuesta explicando cómo lo resolviste, también está bien, así podés marcar esta pregunta como respondida y le puede servir a otros usuarios

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Crear un enlace tipo asset en Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323290/crear-un-enlace-tipo-asset-en-laravel)